# getSupportActionBar() returns null after changing theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I open activity with transparent style, it means that it has this theme at the start:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

After few moments I change theme

```
setTheme(R.style.AppThemeWithActionBar);
```

which looks like this:

```
<style name="AppThemeWithActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

But unfortunately, when I call getSupportActionBar() after changing theme I get null, what is the reason?

Comment: did you change in manifest? or if you have changed it programetically; then call setTheme(R.style.AppThemeWithActionBar) before super.onCreate.

Comment: What if I want to call setTheme after activity is created? I started activity with transition effect and I need to get transparent style when activity is showing, but then I want to show action bar

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to set a style:

**Using `AndroidManifest.xml`**
for Entire Application :

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
</application>
```

for Individual Activity :

```
<application>
    <activity android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
    ...
    </activity>
</application>
```

---

**Programmatically :**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.CustomTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

Comment: You didn't understand my question.

Comment: I understand.. please try this solution : 
`setTheme(R.style.CustomTheme);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: No... as I wrote I want to do it after few moments after super.onCreate, checkout my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change theme at runtime without reloading whole activity. Because I don't want to reload activity, I will have to stop using ActionBar and start using Toolbar.